No debugger available, can not send 'variables'-Cannot find module '/Users/cliu21/scratch/app.js
I am learning about how to use API in Javascript. Then I got a mistake: "/opt/homebrew/bin/node ./app.js"
Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module '/Users/cliu21/scratch/app.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:28:49)
loader:1149
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

This is my code:          
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

console.log("Starting Program");
client.messages
  .list()
  .then(messages => messages.array.forEach(m => console.log(m.sid)));
    
console.log("Gathering message log");

 I have installed node_module and tried to fix the problem about 2hours, but canot fix it. enter image description here
        
How can I fix the problem?

It seems that you are trying running Node.js via VSCode. If you are new to Node.js, I suggest you directly use CLI node <YOUR SCRIPT FILE>

What does this sentence mean?  Just use the command:  node explore.js on the terminal?  I tried, but failed.

Yes. By running the command you won't get that error.
